# Repopulate Form Fields in Rails Form Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a simple user registration page in my rails app that has two fields: name and email. I have client side validation on each text field and server side for the submit button (This is the recommended way right?)

My problem is that I don't know how to repopulate the two fields with the previous values if they submitted it with a mistake. I have tried a few days such as:

`format.html { redirect_to :back, :notice => 'Uh Oh! Something went wrong!', :name => @user.name }` <-- create action
and

`if(params.has_key?(:name))
      @user.name = params[:name]
    end` <-- new action

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is the recommended way to put validation on both client and server side.

Regarding retaining the fields is concerned on redirect the @ variables use to be get destroyed only flash persist up to one redirect.

Either u can pass your validations message in flash which is bad way the good one is to render the form page (good to be make form as seperate partial) and the @ object will be automaticaly map the relevant fields like name, email.

Hope this will help you.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your form: <%= f.error_messages %> and don't redirect because you will lose the posted data.

You could do something like this in your action:

```
if @posted_object.save
   redirect_to ...
else
   render 'your view'
end
```

Comment: Then how can I pass @posted_object to the new page?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that flash can do what I wanted, but I was using it incorrectly.
I had to use:
`flash[:name] = "name"` 
before the redirect instead of `redirect_to :back, :name => "name"`

and in the html
`<% if flash[:name] %>` instead of `<% if params[:name] %>` or `<% name %>`